# Handling Many-To-Many-To-Many Relationships in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, many-to-many

I'm working with AWS DynamoDB for a use-case where I have Users, Groups and Posts. The relationships are as follows:

A User can follow multiple Groups
Each Groups can have multiple Posts.

I need to create an efficient way to retrieve a paginated list of all Posts from all Groups that a User follows. Here's an example of how the relationships are currently stored in DynamoDB:

User follows a Group: `pk:USER#userId sk:FOLLOW#Gorup#groupId`

Group creates an Post: `pk:GROUP#groupId sk:POST#postId`

The challenge I'm facing is the many-to-many relationship between Users and Posts via Groups, and DynamoDB's limitations when it comes to performing complex queries across multiple items.

The straightforward solution of duplicating each Post for each User that follows its parent Group doesn't seem feasible, especially when considering scenarios where a Group has thousands of Posts and is followed by millions of Users.

I'm aware of the potential of using secondary indexes and have thought of querying Groups followed by a User and then querying the Posts for each Group, but this would require multiple reads, which I would like to avoid for cost efficiency.

I don't think the application will have as much users, but someone should be prepared, thats why we are using a horizontally scaling service right?

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: This is an inherently difficult computer science problem. You should read about all the lengths twitter has gone through to optimize their workload, which is a lot like what you're asking for here. (Hint: the difficulty of this problem is a reason they had the famous Fail Whale so often for years.)